# How can I update value after animation in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, animation, svelte

I'm making "wordle" game in Svelte.

**Context**

There is a 2d table, and I wanna give effect to current cell(I know `currentX` and `currentY`). When user types a specific letter, I have to update its position value to the next cell. I coded like below.

```js
typedLetterStore.subscribe(({ letter }) => {
  if (letter === "") {
    return;
  }
  board[currentX][currentY] = letter;

  if (currentY + 1 === COL) {
    if (currentX + 1 < ROW) {
      currentX += 1;
      currentY = 0;
    }
  } else {
    currentY += 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="board">
  {#each board as boardRow, rowIndex}
    <div class="board__row">
      {#each boardRow as element, colIndex}
        <span
          class="board__element"
          class:board__element--current={
            currentY === colIndex &&
            element !== ""}
        >
          {element}
        </span>
      {/each}
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

`board__element--current` gives "scale-down" effect by CSS animation, but it doesn't trigger any effect when I use update logic above(which updates `currentX` and `currentY`). Of course, I can give effect using reverse calculation to the `currentX` and `currentY` to satisfy previous position. But, it doesn't feel natural method. To summarize, I need 2 things.

- Give "scale-down" effect to current position.
- Update `currentX` and `currentY` to the next position

I already tried `afterUpdate` Svelte lifecycle API, but it didn't work.

**Question**

How can I update `currentX` and `currentY` **AFTER** "scale-down" animation end? You can check what is "scale-down" effect in [official wordle game](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) by typing any letter.

Comment: You probably want to look at the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event. You could add a handler and use it like `on:animationend={doUpdate}`.